# does static variable initialized in default constructor?

Tags: java, static, final

```
class Temp{
       final static int x;
     public static void main(String[] args){
    }
}
```

Compilation error: variable x not initialized in the default constructor

Why it says not initialized in default constructor since the variable is static?
What is the role of default constructor here?

Comment: That's because the variable is `final`, you need to initialize it at the moment of its declaration.

Comment: or in a static initializer block

Answer (score 3):

You're right, that error message is not very helpful. A `static final` variable (the convention is generally to put `static` before `final`) must be initialised either at the declaration point or via a static block:

```
final static int x = 0;
//or
final static int y;
static {
  y = 0;
}
```

I can't say any related bug reports so you could submit one if you want.

Comment: Thanx... I tried for final non-static variable also... It gives the same error. In case of final non static... Error is acceptable

Answer (score 1):

It is not only static... it is final static :) 
static final members should be initialized inline or in static block.

Comment: Thanx... But my question was that what is the role of default constructor here

Comment: @RahulGupta it is most definitely **not** the role of _any_ constructor, default or otherwise, to initialize `static` fields, and on that point, the message is misleading.

Comment: @KevinAnderson thanx